# Post method in Retrofit Android

Tags: android, post, retrofit

I have a post api to get some details. I am passing the parameters like this

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        GitHubService github = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);

        Map<String, String> params;
        Params.setAppContext(getApplicationContext());
        params = Params.postCommuteParams(AppUtil.getAuthToken(MainActivity.this), android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE, "");


        Log.d("retrofit param", ""+params.toString());

        Call<CommuteResultVO> call1 = github.callCommute(params);
        call1.enqueue(new Callback<CommuteResultVO>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<CommuteResultVO> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                CommuteResultVO user = response.body();
                Log.d("retrofit", ""+statusCode+"  );
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.d("retrofit", "failed");
            }
        });

    }
```

The log for retrofit param gives all the params.
Log.d("retrofit param", ""+params.toString());

The params are working as this api call is completely working with volley.

This is how I have written the post call in GitHubService class

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/commutes/availability?")
    Call<CommuteResultVO> callCommute(@FieldMap Map<String, String> parameters);
```

But I am getting a statusCode of 404 in the response

Comment: why do you have the `?` after `availability` ?

Comment: the api provided for me have this ? and after this the parameters comes.I tried with removing this ? sign and still the response is 404.

Comment: without `?` the rest looks ok. Are you sure you didn't misspelled something in the url?

Comment: ya I am sure. I even tried this method in the post call to get the parameters Call<CommuteResultVO> callCommute(@Field("parameter") String parameter)

Comment: *I even tried this method in the post call to get the parameters*, what you mean by that ?

Comment: instead of calling FieldMap i tried with Field to get each parameter of the post api

Comment: `404` means resource not found, backend side. It must be somthing wrong with the endpoint itself. Are you able to run it using another client http such as curl or postman ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95311/discussion-between-ranjith-and-blackbelt).

Comment: please check your retrofit compile version.i think you retrofit compile version low..add latest update version